# How to set different divs on same position?

Tags: html, css, position

I am building a horizontal timeline. Click on points, arrows they are all working well.

My problem is: I want to have the detail box always on same place and same size.If I use position fixed then it is almost impossible to make it responsive because the box stay at the same point of screen. Do you have any solution here?

```js
$('.point-text').on('click',function(){
      $('.point-details, .point-arrow, .point-arrow-shade').css('display', 'none');
      if ($(this).siblings('.point-details').css('display') == 'none'){
          console.log("auf");
         $(this).siblings('.point-details').css('display', 'block');
         $(this).siblings('.point-arrow').css('display', 'block');
         $(this).siblings('.point-arrow-shade').css('display', 'block');
      }
    });
    
    $('.point-text').first().click();
```

```css
.h-timeline-container{
       min-height:300px;
         margin-top:70px;
    }
    
    ol.h-timeline-wrap {
     position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        justify-content: space-around;
        display: flex;
        height: 1px;
        background: #d4d4d4;
    }
    
    ol.h-timeline-wrap::before {
     left: -5px;
    }
    ol.h-timeline-wrap::after {
     right: -10px;
     border: 10px solid transparent;
     border-right: 0;
     border-left: 20px solid #9b2;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    /* ---- Timeline elements ---- */
    
    li.h-timeline-point {
        position: relative;
        top: -10px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        font: bold 14px arial;
    }
    li.h-timeline-point::before {
        content: "";
        position: relative;
        top: -10px;
        left: -4px;
        display: block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        z-index: 0;
        border: 4px solid #009FDA;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #009FDA;
    }
    .point-text {
        right: -11px;
        z-index: 2;
        font-size: 25px;
        top: -48px;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: white;
    }
    
    /* ---- Details ---- */
    
    .point-details {
        display:none;
        position: relative;
        right: 50px;
        top: -11px;
        padding: 16px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #002776;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #fff;
        color: black;
        font-weight: normal;
        width: 950px;
    }
    
    
    /* ---- Hover effects ---- */
    
    .point-text:hover .h-timeline-point { 
      color: #28e;
    }
    .point-text:hover{
      cursor: pointer;
      }
    .point-arrow {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 46px;
        display: none;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 20px solid transparent;
        border-right: 20px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 20px solid #002776;
    }
    .point-arrow-shade{
        display: block;
        top: 48px;
        border-bottom: 20px solid #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        border-left: 20px solid transparent;
        border-right: 20px solid transparent;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        left: 0px;
        content: "";
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .h-timeline-point:hover::before {
     background-color: #002776;
     border-color: #002776;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
        .point-details {
            width:800px;
        }
      li.h-timeline-point {
        width:100px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      li.h-timeline-point {
      width:75px;
      }
       .point-details {
            width:700px;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
     li.h-timeline-point {
      width:25px;
      }
       .point-details {
            width:400px;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    
       .point-details {
            width:350px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="h-timeline-container">
    <ol class="h-timeline-wrap">
     <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">1</span><span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-details">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </span></li>
     <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">2</span><span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-details">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </span></li>
     <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">3</span><span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-details">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </span></li>
     <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">4</span><span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-details">4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </span></li>
     <li class="h-timeline-point"><span class="point-text">5</span><span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span> <span class="point-details">5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </span></li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Did you try `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`? A fixed element will always be fixed on your page, however an absolute element will place himself from his first parent with a relative position.

Comment: I tried but then for each point click box will be on different position. What I want , to have box always at same position and arrow will be changed.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your problem but you could create only one detail box and then using some javascript and onclick events from the number buttons, change the content of the details box.

```js
var content1 = "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."
var content2 = "2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."
var content3 = "3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."
var content4 = "4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."
var content5 = "5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."


$('.point-text').on('click', function() {
  $('.point-arrow, .point-arrow-shade').css('display', 'none');
  if ($(this).siblings('.point-arrow').css('display') == 'none') {
    console.log("auf");
    $(this).siblings('.point-details').css('display', 'block');
    var selector = $(this).text();
    var binder = "content" + selector;
    $('.point-details').text(eval(binder));
    $(this).siblings('.point-arrow').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).siblings('.point-arrow-shade').css('display', 'block');
  }
});

$('.point-text').first().click();
```

```css
.h-timeline-container {
   min-height: 300px;
   margin-top: 70px;
 }

 ol.h-timeline-wrap {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0;
   justify-content: space-around;
   display: flex;
   height: 1px;
   background: #d4d4d4;
 }

 ol.h-timeline-wrap::before {
   left: -5px;
 }

 ol.h-timeline-wrap::after {
   right: -10px;
   border: 10px solid transparent;
   border-right: 0;
   border-left: 20px solid #9b2;
   border-radius: 3px;
 }

 /* ---- Timeline elements ---- */

 li.h-timeline-point {
   position: relative;
   top: -10px;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 150px;
   font: bold 14px arial;
 }

 li.h-timeline-point::before {
   content: "";
   position: relative;
   top: -10px;
   left: -4px;
   display: block;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   z-index: 0;
   border: 4px solid #009FDA;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #009FDA;
 }

 .point-text {
   right: -11px;
   z-index: 2;
   font-size: 25px;
   top: -48px;
   position: relative;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: white;
 }

 /* ---- Details ---- */

 .point-details {
   /* display: none; */
   position: relative;
   right: 50px;
   top: -11px;
   padding: 16px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   border: 1px solid #002776;
   font-size: 16px;
   background: #fff;
   color: black;
   font-weight: normal;
   width: 950px;
 }


 /* ---- Hover effects ---- */

 .point-text:hover .h-timeline-point {
   color: #28e;
 }

 .point-text:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .point-arrow {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 46px;
   display: none;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 20px solid #002776;
 }

 .point-arrow-shade {
   display: block;
   top: 48px;
   border-bottom: 20px solid #ffffff;
   position: absolute;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   left: 0px;
   content: "";
   z-index: 2;
 }

 .h-timeline-point:hover::before {
   background-color: #002776;
   border-color: #002776;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
   .point-details {
     width: 800px;
   }

   li.h-timeline-point {
     width: 100px;
   }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   li.h-timeline-point {
     width: 75px;
   }

   .point-details {
     width: 700px;
   }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   li.h-timeline-point {
     width: 25px;
   }

   .point-details {
     width: 400px;
   }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {

   .point-details {
     width: 350px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="h-timeline-container">
  <ol class="h-timeline-wrap">
    <li class="h-timeline-point">
      <span class="point-text">1</span>
      <span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="point-details">1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="h-timeline-point">
      <span class="point-text">2</span>
      <span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="h-timeline-point">
      <span class="point-text">3</span>
      <span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="h-timeline-point">
      <span class="point-text">4</span>
      <span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="h-timeline-point">
      <span class="point-text">5</span>
      <span class="point-arrow-shade">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="point-arrow">&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7dyn2cpb/3/

Comment: Thanks for reply but since i am gonna convert it ftl the javascript solution does not help me

Comment: So you have some jquery in your original code but doesn't want any jquery as an answer?